# insufficient_scope when trying to access files api in Xero with OAuth2

Tags: xero-api

I make a Get request to https://api.xero.com/files.xro/1.0/Folders.
It returns the following response with 'insufficient_scope'.

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Xero-Correlation-Id: 0d0de4f4-9f8f-4592-9150-178ad2fedb25
  Pragma: no-cache
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Client-TLS-ver: tls1.2
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
  Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 04:13:44 GMT
  Server: Kestrel
  WWW-Authenticate: insufficient_scope
  Content-Length: 124
  Expires: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 04:13:44 GMT
}}
```

When authorizing, the scope includes 'file'. Anything else I should include in the scope? Or any other setting missing?

(Requests to accounting.contacts using the same token/tenantid are successful. I use the demo company.)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the scope you'll need when authorising is `files` rather than 'file'. You can check the scopes that are on the token you're using by going to [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) or similar.